# Is this some kind of hashing?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, computational-geometry, hash, hashing

Say I have $n$ vectors $\{ z_i \in \mathbb{R}^D\}_{i=1}^n$ (where $n$ is very large and hence I can't do any calculation which scales as $n$) and I want to create $n$ vectors $\{x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d \}_{i=1}^n$ with $d$ as small as possible, such that $\forall i,j <z_i,z_j>$ is either very close to $<x_i,x_j>$ OR w.h.p $  <z_i,z_j> = <x_i,x_j>$.

- Is there a standard answer known for this - by maybe using hashing?
- One possible way might be to either deterministically or randomly from some distribution pick some $D-d$ coordinates and drop those coordinates from each $x_i$ to get the corresponding $z_i$ such that for each pair on either side either the inner-product is well approximated or is equal with high-probability over the way the coordinates are sampled. Is such a way of sampling known?

---

For the second option one other way to think would be to pick an unit magnitude gaussian vector at random $g \in \mathbb{R}^d \subset \mathbb{R}^D$ and to define $x_i$ as the projection of $z_i$ along $g$. Then indeed one has that $\mathbb{E}_g[ <x_i,x_j>] = <z_i,z_j>$.

But can this above be shown to be true with high concentration or be derandomized?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this matter, but I am aware of the [Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) which gives guarantees similar to what you demand. I would post as an answer, but I honestly am not familiar enough with the inner workings to warrant a complete post.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "possible way" is a known variant of "locality sensitive hashing", which is what you're looking for, I suspect.

Comment: The "standard" LSH references I see do not seem to fit my question. So I am asking what is this "varant" that jbapple refers to. Unless something more specific is said, I don't know what to search for!

Comment: @gradstudent, the method of dropping vector components is referenced in the first paper on LSH.

Comment: You mean somewhere in this paper? https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos598C/Gionis.pdf Are they able to preserve all pair-wise inner-products of any arbitrary set of vectors?